# Is there anyway to detect the change in a form values before and after submit?

Tags: javascript, dom, netsuite

i need to detect any change in a web-page between the pageload and on page saved.

is there any DOM property for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SuiteScript 2.x User event scripts the beforeSubmit(scriptContext) and afterSubmit(scriptContext) entry points both offer scriptContext.newRecord and scriptContext.oldRecord.  You can use these two records to gather/compare values in a function such as.

```
var newRec = scriptContext.newRecord;
var oldRec = scriptContext.oldRecord;

//specify the specific fields you care about
var desiredKeys = ['fieldId1', 'fieldId2', 'fieldId3', 'fieldId4'];

//for each set of keys compare the values
for (var i=0; i < desiredKeys.length; i++){
  var newValue = newRec.getValue({fieldId: desiredKeys[i]});
  var oldValue = oldRec.getValue({fieldId: desiredKeys[i]});
  if (newValue == oldValue){
    log.debug(desiredKeys[i], 'value did not change');
  } else {
    log.debug(desiredKeys[i], 'value did change from: '+ oldValue +' to: '+ newValue);
  }
}
```